# Not finding an easy solution to unban command for Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to get the unban command to work for the past 2 days, but I haven't found an easy solution for it, I keep getting errors like ".find()" isn't a function, or can't define "id". And I just don't get what I need to do. PS.: I am a noobie when it comes to code.
It's also worth mentioning that I have gone through many variations of this code and I have ended at this, probably previous iterations of the code were closer to the actual solution.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "+";

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

});


client.on('message', msg => {
    const { content } = msg;

    if (!content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    const args = content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    switch(command) {

        case "ping" : {
            let latency = Date.now() - msg.createdTimestamp;
            let latencyOfAPI = Math.round(client.ws.ping);
            msg.reply("This is the latency between the message and the response: " + latency + "."  + "\nThis is the API latency: " + latencyOfAPI + ".");

            break;
        } 

        case "pong" : {

            msg.reply("ping");
            break
        }

        case "ban" : {
            const user = msg.mentions.members.first();
            if (user) {
                msg.guild.members.ban(user);
                msg.reply("The user " + user + " has been banned.") 
            } else {
                 return msg.reply("There is no one to ban.").catch(console.error);

            }
            
            break
        }
        case "unban" : {
            const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username == "").id;
            let banList = msg.guild.fetchBans();
            if(banList = 0) {
                return msg.reply("This user isn't in the community, or he is not banned.");
            } else {
                banList.find(user)
                msg.guild.members.unban(user);
                msg.reply("User " + user + " has been unbanned.")
            }
            break
        }

    }
});
client.login('.....');
```

Comment: A user might not necessarily be in the Client users cache. Also, use == for value comparison and === for value and type comparison. = is for assignment of variables.

Comment: Also, fetchBans() return a promise. You should `await` the promise to be resolved before doing anything with it.

Comment: indeed, === is better in many cases.

Comment: That being said though, in this particular case, awaiting fetchBans would give a Collection. Use banList.size to check the number of bans in that guild. banList is guaranteed to be not equal to 0 because they are of different types.

Comment: I just get the "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" instead now, I am confused, sorry if I sound like I don't know anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    case "unban" : {

        const user = client.users.fetch(args[1]).catch((err) => console.log(err));
            user.then((u) => {
        if (!args[1]) {
            return msg.reply("Enter ID to unban")
        } else {
            if (u) {
                msg.guild.members.unban(u).then(() => {
                    msg.reply("The user " + u.username + " has been unbanned.")
                }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
            } else {
                return msg.reply("Cannot Find User")
            }
        }
    })


        break
```

**Usage:** `[prefix]unban [ID]` e.g `[prefix]unban 3426743678738` (type in text channel)

**Tip #1:** Try to use `.then()` & `.catch()` on function which return a promise. You can use `.then()` to confirm that you've successfully unbanned a user and `.catch()` to see why there was a issue with unbanning a user.

**Tip #2:** Make an if statement which checks if the user running this command has the right permissions before trying the code i.e `BAN_MEMBERS` & `ADMINISTRATOR`

**Also Note:** `.fetchBans()` returns a **collection** and **Promise**

Comment: Shouldn't you first verify if args[1] exist before fetching by its value?